# Saving values from a variable to an array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, latitude-longitude

I have a long string variable that contains coordinates
I want to keep each coordinate in a separate cell in the array according to Lat and Lon..
For example. The following string:

```
string = "(33.110029967689556, 35.60865999564635), (33.093492845160036, 35.63955904349791), (33.0916232355565, 35.602995170206896)";
```

I want this:

```
arrayX[0] = "33.110029967689556";
arrayX[1] = "33.093492845160036";
arrayX[2] = "33.0916232355565";
arrayY[0] = "35.60865999564635";
arrayY[1] = "35.63955904349791";
arrayY[2] = "35.602995170206896";
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Oz, I think it would be helpful that you describe what have you tried so far and what difficulties you have faced so people can come with a specific answer. Otherwise I'm afraid the best answer you can will get is "Just split the string"

Comment: Please accept one of the answers to close this question. If none of the answers worked for you, you need to add more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substr to modify sub string, it allow you to do that with a little line of code.

```
$array_temp = explode('),', $string);

$arrayX = [];
$arrayY = [];

foreach($array_temp as $at)
{
  $at = substr($at, 1);
  list($arrayX[], $arrayY[]) = explode(',', $at);

}

print_r($arrayX);
print_r($arrayY);
```

Comment: Where do you define `$X_temp` ?

Comment: @executable it was a mistake, this is variable from my first answer

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion, working example here: https://3v4l.org/W99Uu

```
$string = "(33.110029967689556, 35.60865999564635), (33.093492845160036, 35.63955904349791), (33.0916232355565, 35.602995170206896)";

// Split by each X/Y pair
$array = explode("), ", $string);

// Init result arrays
$arrayX = array();
$arrayY = array();

foreach($array as $pair) {
    // Remove parentheses
    $pair = str_replace('(', '', $pair);
    $pair = str_replace(')', '', $pair);

    // Split into two strings
    $arrPair = explode(", ", $pair);

    // Add the strings to the result arrays
    $arrayX[] = $arrPair[0];
    $arrayY[] = $arrPair[1];
}
```

Comment: what if the string not ending `"), "`

Comment: @Pascal `),` is the separator, it doesn't need to be at the very end. Even if it is at the very end, that's no issue either, you just have to check for empty values from `explode()`. And I don't see your answer treating it any different.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably to use a [regex](https://php.net/manual/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) to match each tuple:

- Each number is a combination of digits and `.`: the regex `[\d\.]+` matches that;
- Each coordinate has the following format: `(`, number, `,`, space, number,`)`. The regex is `\([\d\.]+,\s*[\d\.]+\)`.
- Then you can capture each number by using parenthesis: `\(([\d\.]+),\s*([\d\.]+)\)`. This will produce to capturing groups: the first will contain the X coordinate and the second the Y.

This regex can be used with the method [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/function.preg-match-all.php).

```php
<?php

$string = '(33.110029967689556, 35.60865999564635), (33.093492845160036, 35.63955904349791), (33.0916232355565, 35.602995170206896)';

preg_match_all('/\(([\d\.]+)\s*,\s*([\d\.]+)\)/', $string, $matches);

$arrayX = $matches['1'];
$arrayY = $matches['2'];

var_dump($arrayX);
var_dump($arrayY);
```

For a live example see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/082e8454486dc568a6557058fef68d6f10c8dbd0

Answer (score 0):

You need first to split the string into an array. Then you clean the value to get only the numbers. Finally, you put the new value into the new array.

```
<?php
$string = "(33.110029967689556, 35.60865999564635), (33.093492845160036, 35.63955904349791), (33.0916232355565, 35.602995170206896)";
$loca = explode(", ", $string);

$arr_x = array();
$arr_y = array();

$i = 1;
foreach($loca as $index => $value){
    $i++;
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
      $arr_x[] = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $value);
    }else{
        $arr_y[] = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $value);
    }
}

print_r($arr_x);
print_r($arr_y);
```

You can test it here :
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4bf04e7aabeba15ecfa114d8951eb771610a43a4